# Wordpress Woocommerce - понять причину смены группы админа на покупателя

Tags: wordpress, woocommerce

Помогите пожалуйста понять причину смены группы админа на покупателя. Есть сайт на wp + woocommerce и есть проблема - статус админ акка пару раз в день сам собой меняется на статус покупателя.
Т.е у админ юзера стандартные данные в бд:
id = 1
поле wp_usermeta с a:1:{s:13:"administrator";b:1;}
поле wp_user_level со значением 10
А меняется само собой на wp_usermeta a:1:{s:8:"customer";b:1;} и естественно все права админа у админ юзера теряются, надо снова лезть в бд и вручную менять обратно это значение.
Не могу понять почему так может происходить, подскажите в чем может быть проблема и как решить? Вот список плагинов на сайте:
[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Поскольку на каком-то форуме вы уже ответили, что проблема в плагине из сомнительного источника, то этот вопрос следует закрыть.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Нашел в чем проблема. Проблема была в плагине PGS Woo Api от Potenza Global Solutions. Я покупал их лицензию, а оказалось что она распространяется только на один домен, а я ключ ввел на 2 домена. В итоге разработчик плагина через доступ к апи менял админ юзера на покупателя. Якобы хочешь юзать - купи еще одну версию для второго домена и юзай.